# Set "this" keyword of App.vue in Vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I found a seloution for how to access to vue-router and other services that works only inside the vue component. In the created option of App.vue i save the "this" of vue app inside state of vuex.

does it's a good way or can make some problems in future?

instead to write:

`this.$router.push('route-name')`

from some component, is save the `this` keyword in the state as `context` key for example,
and now from the Actions i'm using the `context` instead `this`
such like this:
`state.context.router.push('route-name')`
and its works..

my question is if its good solution or not.

Comment: Can you please include the necessary code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now it is kinda hard to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to use the router outside of a vue component? This question could be a lot easier to understand if you included some example code.

Comment: no it's not only for the router, it's also require for other things such as quasar dialogs that required the "this" keyword as "parent" key to create a dialog, and for much more things.

Comment: Generally Vue just exposes the router and other things on `this` purely as a convenience. You could simply import the router instance from anywhere and use it without `this` in components; it would just make code slightly more complex and less flexible (because you're importing one specific router, not whatever router you assign to your Vue instance). So… just make sure you have exactly one place where you instantiate router, then `import` it in vuex.

Comment: It's possible but not a good practice. It's a coincidence that `this` is Vue instance that is not documented afaik

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not a good solution, if you want to use `this`, you should try with the actions or getter returned value, inside a Vue file instead using it directly in an action.

I'm giving an example and an explanation

Example:

Getter:

```
export function getRedirect(state){
 return state.routerName
}
```

Vue file:

```
<template>
Page 
<button @onClick="redirect" > Redirect </button>
</template>
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default: {
   computed:{
      ...mapGetters('VuexStoreName',['getRedirect'])
   },
   methods:{
        redirect(){
            this.$router.push(this.getRedirect)
        } 
   }
}
</script>
```

So, instead of using the redirect inside an JS file, creating an action and passing this inside the parameter or getting it by state, you'll be using it correctly in a Vue file.

The probblem setting `this` in the state is that when it changes the instance saved will not change, and you'll have to update every time and everywhere. And calling `this` inside a Vue file, it'll always be updated